# Determine the number of functions that have at least one integer $x$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ for which $f(x) = x$.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

The function is $f\colon\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\to\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

I'm assuming that since there needs to be at least one integer $x$ where $f(x) = x$ and there is $n$ integers in the function, then the integer $x$ can be a possibility of $n$ integers. So the answer would be that there are n number of functions that have at least one integer?

Am I getting some where with that or is it completely wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What kind of functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "there's n integers in the function"?

Comment: @YuriyS This is all thats in the original question. Let n ≥ 1 be an integer. A function f : {1,2,...,n} → {1,2,...,n} is called awesome, if there is at least one integer x in {1,2,...,n} for which f(x) =x.
Determine the number of awesome functions.

Comment: Is $f$ meant to be onto? For $n=2$ can you list all the functions that satisfy the rule you want?  You say there are $2$ of them and I can't imagine which two you are thinking of.

Comment: With $n=2$, I'd say there were three if you do not require onto, and only one if you do.  The three I see are $f(1)=1=f(2),f(1)=2=f(2),f(x)=x$.  Of course only the last one is onto.

Comment: @lulu, what's wrong with $ f(x)=x^k$ where $ k \in \mathbb{R}$? They all obey $f (1)=1$. What am I missing?3

Comment: @YuriyS  Unless I am badly misreading the OP is looking for functions from the finite set $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$ to itself.

Comment: @lulu, thank you, I get it now. Didn't have discrete math, not used to it

Comment: @YuriyS  If you also require that $f$ be a permutation, then this is a well studied problem  (the complement are the so-called [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)).  If you do not require that $f$ be a permutation then they are a lot easier to count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we consider the  set of functions that do not map any element to the same element..now we compute the cardinality of that set. if we take any arbitrary integer $I$ then there are remaining $(N-1)$ positions where the function should go so there are $(N-1)^N$ such function and as there are $N^N$ many function from the domain to range. So there are $N^N-(N-1)^N$  such functions.